# Matrix transformation

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory

I want to show that

$(I-H^T(-s)H(s))^{-1}$ has no poles on the imaginary axis

with $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ and $H^T(-s)=-B^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^T$

is equivalent to $M_\gamma$ has no purely imaginary eigenvalues.

$M_\gamma =
\left( \begin{matrix}
A &  \frac{1}{\gamma}BB^{T} \\
-\frac{1}{\gamma}C^{T}C  &  -A^T \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$

My approach:
$n=dim(A)$

$det(sI-M_\gamma)=det(sI-A)det(sI+A^T)+\frac{1}{\gamma^{2n}}det(BB^{T})det(C^{T}C)=0$
$\implies 1+det(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}BB^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^TC(sI-A)^{-1})=0$

But it is still not:

$I+\frac{1}{\gamma^2}B^T(sI+A)^{-T}C^TC(sI-A)^{-1}B=(I-H^T(-s)H(s))=0$

Where is my mistake? Sign mistake?

Remark: $H(s)$ is a strictly causal and stable state-space system and s is the Laplace-variable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like it has been assigned as an exercise

Comment: No, it is not an exercise. I want to understand the proof: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_241JS11_lec12.pdf

Comment: It would help much more if you would give me some hints on my mistakes instead of putting it as an off-topic.

Comment: I think http://math.stackexchange.com might be a better site for this question